# Interpreting the residual plot

Tags: machine-learning, multiple-regression, data-visualization, error

I'm new to Machine Learning, I have difficulty in interpreting this residual plot(multiple regression) to find out whether the error is random or not(following some pattern). Would you please share your insights on how to interpret residual plots in general?

Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well residual plots are a short graphical way to check how your error is distributed. It should be randomly with a mean on all sectors on zero.

In short it's a graphically check for your distribution. Not random errors are easily seen like in following picture [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdDxa.png)

[image: Different examples for]

So in generell, if you distribution follows a certain pattern, it's not random. In your case it's hard to tell, you have not enough data. It seems fine, but maybe datapoints 2-5 are not random (they all are nearly same level). More simulations would show if there is a pattern.

For other examples and easy explanation check this [link](http://docs.statwing.com/interpreting-residual-plots-to-improve-your-regression/), there are a lot of nicely explained sites which try to explain it. For a math orientate attempt, check the paper [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdDxa.png)

---

1. THE EXAMINATION OF RESIDUAL PLOTS by Zongwu Cai , Chih-ling Tsai ,Xizhi Wu